# Serverless framework and path mapping from tsconfig.json don't work

Tags: typescript, webpack, serverless-framework, serverless, tsconfig

I have a path mapping defined in the tsconfig.json file like this

```
"paths": {
      "~/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
```

and it works with `ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register`, but when it comes to lambdas that are compiled from `.ts` to `.js` files with the help of `serverless-plugin-typescript` plugin, it doesn't work.

I can't do this inside my lambdas `import * as db from '~/db/psql';` any more.

I know why and that's ok, but what can I do to make it work.

I'm trying to switch to `serverless-plugin-typescript` to compile `.ts` files to `.js` files. Before, I was using **webpack** with `tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin` and that worked, but I would like to avoid webpack for compiling lambdas.

Comment: did you get any solution for that ?

Answer (score 2):

After much digging I found out that serverless does not support the pathing options offered by typescript.

For anyone else it appears the options are:

1) Copy the code

2) Utilize Webpack plugin to override servlesss and allow setting the rootDir in typescript

3) Symlink your shared module code to the each of your microservices directories. I wrote a bash script that will symlink a directory called "_shared" to all directories one level under a parent directory called "microservices":

`find microservices ! -path microservices -type d -maxdepth 1 -d -exec ln -s ../../_shared ./{} \;`

You'll then want to add each symlink to your .gitignore:

`/microservices/**/_shared`

So the workflow for the project is:

1. First time you clone the repo, run the bash script to create the symlinks
2. When you are in a microservices sub one level directory, reference imports from _shared from the symlink on that same level
3. Make and commit all changes to the top level _shared directory